# DI, Guice and Strategy Pattern

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, strategy-pattern

Suppose I have the following base class, Queen and Knight as its derivatives. WeaponBehaviour is an interface. I can't figure out how to inject weapons using Guice depending on the concrete GameCharacter type.

```
public abstract class GameCharacter {
    @Inject
    protected WeaponBehaviour weapon;

    public GameCharacter() {

    }

    public void fight() {
        weapon.useWeapon();
    }

    public void setWeapon(WeaponBehaviour weapon) {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does each character type only have one weapon type that it uses?

Comment: The default weapon type configured should be injected at instantiation, but it can be changed through the setter of the base class during runtime as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [Binding Annotations](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations#Binding_Annotations).

A subclass:

```
class GimliSonOfGloin extends GameCharacter {

    @Inject
    public void setWeapon(@Axe WeaponBehaviour weapon) {
        super.setWeapon(weapon);
    }
}
```

The Annotation:

```
@BindingAnnotation 
@Target({ FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD }) 
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Axe {}
```

The Binding:

```
bind(WeaponBehaviour.class)
    .annotatedWith(Axe.class)
    .to(MyAxe.class);
```