# Google Guice + strategy pattern + reflection

Tags: java, reflection, dependency-injection, guice

I am familiar with Google Guice, at least with basics. I now use strategy pattern with annotations (answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667134/di-guice-and-strategy-pattern)) to format messages based on target device.

I have an interface called MessageFormatter.

```
public interface MessageFormatter{
    public String format(String input);
}
```

I have many implementations of this interface. Basically those implementations format short messages based on target display - big screen, cell phone etc. A message is obtained from another server.

What I'd like to do is to SEND FORMATTERS FROM ONE SERVER TO ANOTHER. By sending formatters I mean sending implementations of MessageFormatter interface. I already know how to use reflection to load a class at runtime and use it.

What I need to do is to plug those implementations in at runtime, making the container aware of those new classes, injecting them instead of older ones. Is this possible with Google Guice ?

Comment: By "another server" you mean different JVM?

Comment: Well, I think sending `.class` file through the network and load it dynamically would bit a hack. I would prefer to modularize the application by creating a different Java project with the formatters and add it as a dependency of your servers. Is it a requirement to load formatters dynamically?

Comment: Formatters are my pet project to test if this is possible combined with dependency injection pattern. The real project is about p2p distributed crypto algorithms ;) So yes, it is a requirement.

Comment: I know this question is about Guice, but I have to say that dynamically adding services at run time is what HK2 (https://hk2.java.net/) is very good at (also at removing them dynamically if the need arises).  For example, HK2 dynamically adds and removes implementations of the asadmin command line services in GlassFish all the time

Comment: Thank you for you comment jwells, every idea is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: What about expose the `MessageFormatter` as a OSGi service? You can redeploy just that `MessageFormatter` on the fly. Guice should nicely play with OSGi via `PeaBerry` -> https://github.com/ops4j/peaberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guice has third party support for OSGi, which would allow using Guice to plug in services that are dynamically changing during runtime. There are OSGi containers that can monitor your file system for new bundles containing additional class files to load (e.g [Apache Felix File Install](https://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-file-install.html)).

Here is some additional resources

- [Guice's OSGi wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/OSGi)
- [Peaberry's User Guide](https://github.com/ops4j/peaberry/wiki/User-Guide)

Comment: Your answer made it clear. I've never heard about OSGi before. I was working hard today to make it work and it actually works. Thanks for the tips. ;)